# Lie Automorphisms

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

Take $X$ to be a Lie group. Define a Lie automorphism of $X$ to be a group isomorphism from $X$ to itself which is also a homeomorphism. Define $Aut(X)$ to be the group of Lie automorphisms of $X$ under composition. Then we can see that $Aut(X)$ is a subgroup of the homeomorphism group, $Homeo(X)$. Is there anything to be said of $Aut(X)$ as a subgroup?

Answer (score 2):

First note that $Aut(X)$ is a subgroup of the diffeomorphism group of $X$.

In nice cases, for example if $\pi_0(X)$ is finite ($\pi_0(X)$ is the component group of $X$), then $Aut(X)$ is a Lie group itself. This is a theorem of Hochschild. (Paper: The Automorphism group of a Lie Group)

However in some certain cases one can say definitively more. For example, if $X=SU(2)$, then every automorphism is inner.

Do you have any concrete type of Lie groups in mind?

Comment: Thank you! I am looking at the relationship between $Aut(X)$ and $\pi_0(Homeo(X))$ (or $\pi_0(Diffeo(X))$) in particular. As for a concrete example how about the $n$-torus?

Comment: Well, the automorphismgroup of a $n$-torus $T^n=(S^1)^n$ is just $\mathbb{Z}^n$ isn't it. If I recall it correctly you have $\pi_0(Homeo(T^n))=GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$, but I dont know if this is just a funny coincidence.

Comment: I believe you mean the automorphism group of $T^n$ is $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ since these are the automorphisms of $\pi_1(T^n)=\mathbb{Z}^n$. Moreover, $\pi_0(Homeo(T^n))=GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Also, is there more to be said if $X$ is connected?